# What code from other programming languages can precisely approximate $D$?

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, problem-solving, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

Consider set $\left\{\left. T(c,d)\right|c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$, a subset of rational numbers that is defined in the form of a double variable function. For example, $T$ could equal $\left\{\left.\frac{2c+1}{2d}\right|c,d\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$.

I want to find a the most and efficient code from a  programming language that  can numerically approximate $D$

$$D=\lim_{(a,b)\to(-\infty,\infty)}\left(\lim_{(r,t)\to(\infty,\infty)}D'(a,b,r,t)\right) \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad (1)$$

$$D'(a,b,r,t)=\frac{\sum\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\sum\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]}\left|T\cap V(a,b,k,n)\right|}{\sum\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\sum\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]}\left|V(a,b,k,n)\right|} \quad \quad \ \ \ (2)$$

Where $V(a,b,k,n)=\left\{\left.\frac{m}{2^k n}\in[a,b]\right|m\in\mathbb{Z} \land \gcd\left(m,2^kn\right)=1\right\}$.

Solving $D$ explicitly is impossible to do with programming. Approximating $D$ would be simpler; however, we must view $D$ in a slightly different way.

The method to approximate $D$ should go along these lines:

For fixed values of real numbers $a,b$, we take the limit of $D'(a,b,r,t)$ as $(r,t)\to\infty$. As $a$ is fixed to a large negative number and $b$ is fixed to a large positive number $D'(a,b,r,t)$ should approximate closer to $D$ if a limit exists. (Note that I am not focusing on how $a$ varies with $b$ or vice versa as $D$ is heavily dependent on $r$ and $t$.)

To approximate $D$ in this manner, I used Mathematica where I changed $D'(a,b,r,t)$ into a different form.

$$\frac{\left|T\cap\left(\bigcup\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\bigcup\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]} V(a,b,k,n)\right)\right|}{\left|\bigcup\limits_{\left\{k\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\cap[0,r]}\bigcup\limits_{\left\{n\in\text{odd}\right\}\cap[0,t]}V(a,b,k,n)\right|} \qquad \qquad \qquad (3)$$

and created a [technique in this link](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/147520/what-is-the-best-method-for-solving-da-b-r-t-under-a-5-minute-computation-ti) to approximate $D$. However the technique has two problems.

1. It is unable to set $(r,t)\to\infty$ for fixed $a,b$
2. The programming won't compute for larger values of $r,t$ and $a,b$

Moreover, no one was able to reduce the computation time of my solution or offer a different method from Mathematica.

I know little about other kinds of programming languages so I will ask this:

What code from other programming languages can efficiently approximate $D$ for large fixed values of $a$, $b$ as $(r,t)\to\infty$?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the mathematica syntax, but from what I saw in the provided link, you explicitly enumerate every element in $V(a,b,k,n)$ and also in $T(c,d)$, then compare the two lists? Also, your definition of $D(a;b,r,t)$ feels weird to me (or I don't understand it). To me it seems like you should define it without the limit, but that you're interested in the limit of $D(a,b,r,t)$ for large values of $a,b,r,t$... ?

Comment: As for my doubts, not really. I still think it makes more sense to define $D(a,b,r,t)=\frac{\sum_k\sum_n\lvert T\cap V(a,b,k,n)\rvert}{\sum_k\sum_n\lvert V(a,b,k,n)\rvert}$ and then to have a look at $D=\lim_{a,b,r,t}D(a,b,r,t)$. Because the way you define $D(a,b,r,t)$, it does not depend at all on the "variables" $a,b,r,t$. But this is nitpicking I guess, since the precise definition does not change what you want to compute/approximate. I am however curious as to how you proved that expression (1) is equivalent to expression (2), because the only formal proof of that I can think of now...

Comment: ... kinda relies on Cesaro summation/convergence. And it short, it requires the limit to exist. Since I don't really know the context in which you want to use this computation, I have no clue whether the limit is well-defined in each use case. If we assume expression (2) to be correct, I think it is possible to simplify the enumeration of $\bigcup_k\bigcup_nV(a,b,k,n)$ so you don't have to check "duplicates", which should save you some time. No clue as to whether this will let you run this in under the 5min time constraint you have on mathematica.

Comment: Also, unless your $T$ is bounded is some way, I doubt you can get around the limitation of "setting $(r,t)\rightarrow\infty$", regardless of what language you use. For the rest, any differences would boil down to how easily you can code the computation, but as I've said I'm unfamiliar with mathematica so I wouldn't be able to recommend an easier software/language. I'll have a look at a potential faster algorithm later.

Comment: I realized my cesaro comment on why $(1)=(2)$ doesn't work, but I can't edit my comment anymore. Also, is it important that you can vary $a$ independently from $b$? From only the description, it seems like you could just use $a=-b$.

Comment: Didn't have time to make sure it made sense, been a little busy these days.

Comment: I've started looking into it again for a bit, and I have to ask, in what context do you need this? I didn't notice because your definitions were strange to me, but $\lim_{r,t}\bigcup_k\bigcup_n V(a,b,k,n)=[a,b]\cap\mathbb Q$. If you also include the limit in $a,b$ you get the set of rationals. Then when I look at your example definition of $T$, I really think you are better off solving this problem with maths rather than programming. I'm not even sure whether the limits themselves make sense, but this looks like a problem for measure theory.

Comment: @N.Bach I create a definition that extends natural density to rational numbers. Note this is completely different from taking the asymptotic density of pairs of integers. Inorder to define such a density, I split $\mathbb{Q}\cap[a,b]$ into a finite number finite disjoint sets. Then I took the limit as $r,t$ and $a,b$ to make the finite number of sets appraoch infinity.

Comment: Oh, I've never studied this topic of "natural density", but now that I've taken a look at them, this whole things make so much more sense to me. And I have to re-iterate, the limit for $r,t$ infinite isn't guaranteed to exist, so unless you exploit the structural properties of $T$, I don't think there's any way a computer will be able to do that. If I have time, I'll post an answer this week-end for computing $D'$.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to simply pick an enumeration of $\mathbb{Q}$ and calculate the natural density from that? The difficulty of the computation will depend on what enumeration you choose, but the one you effectively came up with in your post doesn't look like it will make things any easier.

Comment: @Contravariant Wouldn't different enumerations have different results? I chose my enumeration for specific reasons. I wish I could explain them in more detail but right now the focus is on my definition of $D$.

Comment: I half agree with you Arbuja... Assuming the limit over $r,t$ exists, then no matter the enumeration you choose, the limit should be identical. But since we're unable to actually compute the limit, the computed values should vary. It is unclear to me how large the impact of this choice is. Since we don't even know if there is a limit, it feels more useful to choose an enumeration that fits your problem. [As a reminder, take this with a grain of salt, since I basically don't know anything about natural densities.]

Comment: @N.Bach Actually I'm pretty sure the exact value will depend on what enumeration you choose. All I'm saying is that, if possible, it would be better to choose an enumeration that makes the calculation easier.

Comment: @Arbuja I did a bit of research, and it looks like the enumeration you get by traversing the Calkin-Wilf tree can be generated pretty quickly using integer arithmetic. This only covers the positive rationals, but it's pretty easy to add 0 and the negative rationals. However without more structure on $T$ it's going to be difficult to say anything about the accuracy of such an approximation.

Answer (score 2):

So, let's have a look at
$W(a,b,r,t)=\bigcup_k\bigcup_n V(a,b,k,n)$. If we put it into words, $W$ is the collection of rationals in $[a,b]$ whose irreducible form $\frac pq$ satisfies
$q\le 2^{\lfloor r\rfloor}\times\lfloor t\rfloor$. To simplify a bit, I'll just write it as
$W(a,b,M)=\left\{\frac pq\in[a,b]\mid \gcd(p,q)=1,\ q\le M \right\}$. If you get the prime factorization of $M$, it's easy to go back to the $2^rt$ formulation.
Speaking of prime factorization, it's probably the easiest way to go through all elements of $W$ without having to check for potential duplicates.
In your mathematica code, you were checking every pairs $(p,q)$
that satisfied $q\le M$ and $p\in[aq,bq]$. Instead I suggest using prime factorization to only check pairs whose gcd is $1$.

Notice that $W(a,b,M)=W(0,b,M)\cup W(a,0,M)$, and if we can find $W(0,b,M)$ we can get $W(a,0,M)$ by computing $W(0,-a,M)$ and multiplying everyone by $-1$. So let's roll with $W(0,b,M)$. Let $P$ be every prime number smaller than $Mb$ and $Q$ all those smaller than $M$. Obviously $Q\subseteq P$, if you pick a subset of coefficients $q_1,\ldots,q_J\in Q$ and integer coefficients $\beta_1,\ldots,\beta_J\ge 1$, let
$q=\prod_{j=1}^Jq_j^{\beta_j}$.
Then an integer $p$ defines a valid rational $\frac pq$ if and only if there exist $p_1,\ldots,p_I\in P\setminus Q$ with $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_I\ge 1$ such that
$p=\prod_{i=1}^Ip_i^{\alpha_i}$.
So if you use some while loop and maybe a recursive function, you can go over every valid $(p,q)$ pair only once. Hopefully, you can also test then and there whether the corresponding rational belongs to $T$ or not, which spares you the need to store them in memory.

One problem you could raise is about the cost of listing the prime numbers smaller than some threshold. Honestly, no clue. Depending on what you choose, you could just get a list of them from somewhere. Actually, it's probably better if you can just treat that step as a pre-processing, so you don't really care about its computational cost. Also, if you do this smartly you can just use mathematica and bypass the 5 minutes limitation. For a given $W(a,b,r,t)$, you could split it into smaller subsets and run the computation on each smaller subsets, and add the whole thing up.

---

#### Pseudo-code (detailed)

Below is a fairly detailed pseudo-code explaining how to loop over admissible pairs $(p,q)$. I couldn't think of a simpler structure so I wanted to make sure I wouldn't neglect something important in the complexity analysis later on.

I'll assume that given a pair $(p,q)$ you have some way to test if $p/q$ belongs to $T$.
Given some $q=\prod_{j=1}^Jq_j^{\beta_j}$, $b$, and $P$, it is easy to test every possible $p$. Let $P'=P\setminus\{q_1,\ldots,q_J\}$.
The recursive function below can perform this test.

```
Function Recursive_P(
    list of prime P',
    current numerator p,
    current denominator q,
    parameter b
    ) :

%%% Initialization
count_T := 0 ;
count_W := 0 ;
Choose any p_i in P'
P' := P'\{p_i} ;    % remove p_i from the list of prime
alpha_i_max := floor( ln( (b*q)/p ) / ln( p_i ) ) ;    % compute the maximum exponent for p_i

%%% Main loop
% test other numerator values when alpha_i == 0
tmp_T,tmp_W := Recursive_P( P', p, q, b) ;    % test the other possible numerators that use the primes in P'
count_T += tmp_T ;    % update the counters
count_W += tmp_W ;

% perform the test when alpha_i > 0
for 1 <= alpha_i <= alpha_i_max :    % loop over admissible exponents
    count_W += 1 ;    % each iteration corresponds to a valid p,q pair in W
    p := p*p_i ;    % the new numerator to test

    if (p,q) in T then :    % performing the test
        count_T += 1 ;
    end if

    tmp_T,tmp_W := Recursive_P( P', p, q, b) ;    % test the other possible numerators that use the primes in P'
    count_T += tmp_T ;    % update the counters
    count_W += tmp_W ;
end for

%%% Return values
return count_T,count_W
```

Once we have that, it suffices to loop over the possible values of $q$

```
function Recursive_Q(
    list of primes Q,
    list of primes P,
    current denominator q,
    maximum magnitude M
    ) :

%%% Initialization
count_T := 0 ;
count_W := 0 ;
Choose any q_j in Q
Q := Q\{q_j} ;    % remove q_j from the list of primes
P := P\{q_j} ;
beta_j_max := floor( ln( M/q ) / ln( q_j ) ) ;    % compute the maximum exponent for q_j

%%% Main loop
% perform the test for beta_j == 0
tmp_T,tmp_W := Recursive_P( P, 1, q, b);    % test the numerators for the current q
count_T += tmp_T ;    % update the counters
count_W += tmp_W ;

tmp_T,tmp_Q := Recursive_Q( Q, P, q, M) ;    % test other combinations with the remaining primes in Q
count_T += tmp_T ;    % update the counters
count_W += tmp_W ;

% perform the test for beta_j > 0
for 1 <= beta_j <= beta_j_max :    % loop over admissible exponents
    q := q*q_j ;    % the new denominator to test

    tmp_T,tmp_W := Recursive_P( P, 1, q, b);    % test the numerators for the current q
    count_T += tmp_T ;    % update the counters
    count_W += tmp_W ;

    tmp_T,tmp_Q := Recursive_Q( Q, P, q, M) ;    % test other combinations with the remaining primes in Q
    count_T += tmp_T ;    % update the counters
    count_W += tmp_W ;
end for

%%% Return values
return count_T,count_W
```

In order to compute your ratio, and assuming you already know $P$ and $Q$, it suffices to call the function
`Recursive_Q( P, Q, 1, M)` once to obtain both the numerator and denominator.

---

#### Complexity analysis

The above detailed version shows that we can implement the below pseudo-code

```
count_W := 0 ;
count_T := 0 ;

for p/q in W(a,b,2^rt):
    count_W += 1 ;
    if p/q in T then :
        count_T += 1 ;
    end if
end for

return count_T / count_W
```

When it comes to "time complexity" only, this short version is equivalent to the detailed one above. Let's say that testing if a rational $p/q$ belongs to $T$ or not has time complexity $C$.
(Note that in your example, we can consider $C=1$.)
Then this version has an overall "runtime complexity"
$\mathcal O(C\left\lvert W\right\rvert)$.

Now this analysis excluded the required pre-processing steps, which consists in computing the list of primes $P$ and $Q$. We need every prime whose magnitude is at most
$2^rt\times\max\{\lvert a\rvert;\ b\}$, I'll denote this value by $M$.
I don't know that much about the structure of prime numbers among integers, but at least this is possible in time linear to $M\times\lvert P\rvert$.
If you must include pre-processing, you end up with a time complexity of
$\mathcal O(C\left\lvert W\right\rvert+M\lvert P\rvert)$.

Now as for memory/space complexity, this only depends on the size of $P$, and the level of recursion we reach. Each call to a "recursive_P/Q" function needs a bit of memory to store their temporary values, and the deeper you will ever go is $\lvert Q\rvert+\lvert P\rvert=\mathcal O(\lvert P\rvert)$.
Each instance needs to store its own list of "remaining prime", so in the end the space/memory complexity is $\mathcal O(\lvert P\rvert^2)$.
Pre-processing space complexity is only $\mathcal O(\lvert P\rvert)$, so we can ignore it in this case.

---

### OP's previous method

#### Pseudo-code

```
W := {}    % empty list (or preferably a set?)

% building W
for k (integer) in [0; r] :
    for n (odd integer) in [0; t] :
        for m integer in [a2^rt; b2^rt] :
            add m / (2^rt) in W
        end for    % m loop
    end for    % n loop
end for    % k loop

delete duplicate rationals in W    % already done for a set


% proceed to count as in my proposal
count_W := 0 ;
count_T := 0 ;
for p/q in W:
    count_W += 1 ;
    if p/q in T then :
        count_T += 1;
    end if
end for

return count_T / count_W
```

Let's treat the first part as pre-processing, and the later as runtime.

The runtime part has the same time complexity
$\mathcal O(C\lvert W\rvert)$
since it is basically the same. (Although I am unclear how efficient the mathematica code OP used actually is.)
However this time, the loop explicitly use the whole set $W$ which needs to be stored in memory, so space complexity is $\mathcal O(\lvert W\rvert)$
as opposed to the previous $\mathcal O(\lvert P\rvert^2)$.
And for large values of $r$ and $t$, $\lvert P\rvert^2$ should be a lot smaller than $\lvert W\rvert$.

Now let's take a look at the pre-processing part.
The three nested loops bring us to a total time-space complexity of
$\mathcal O(r\times t\times (b-a)2^rt)=\mathcal O(rtM)$. For larger values of $r$ or $t$, I intuitively think that $\lvert P\rvert$ should be smaller since prime numbers get scarcer and scarcer, but maybe not since it is a weird parametrization... In practice I think that just finding primes should be faster. Even in the off chance it is not faster, the additional step needed to delete duplicates, whether it is handled by a set-like data structure, or done after the fact, it will cost you quite a bit. According to the c++ documentation on their "set" class, expect at least $\mathcal O(rtM\log\lvert P\rvert)$ if you do the deletion properly.
In summary for the pre-processing, time complexity of
$\mathcal O(rtM\log\lvert P\rvert)$, and I believe
$rt>\lvert P\rvert> \log\lvert P\rvert$, so that would be worse than the previous $\mathcal O(M\lvert P\rvert)$.
For space complexity, your current mathematica version is
$\mathcal O(rtM)$, but you could probably make it easily into
$\mathcal O(\lvert P\rvert)$.

---

#### Conclusion

If $rt\log\lvert P\rvert \ge \lvert P\rvert$, then my proposed method is both asymptotically faster and uses less space. Actually, the greater the $r,t$ (or $M$) values, the more you gain.
If you can split the computation with a pre-processing, it is also feasible to split $W$ into more manageable slices. If you enumerate $W$ directly, it's very easy (your current approach). If you do not fully enumerate $W$, it's possible to split the loop in my method by remembering what prime numbers with what exponent you used, but it's a little more tricky to do that.

If pre-processing/splitting the loop is possible,
the greatest gain with my method is less memory usage, but I don't think you're worried about that... Except maybe if your previous method actually used up all available memory.
If pre-processing is off the table, my method is much faster in its "pre-processing" steps.

Comment: Thank you, this is helpful. However, were you able to find a method from other programming languages, similar to [the method I used in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/147520/edit), to approximate $D$.

Comment: @Arbuja Do you a combination of pre-existing methods you can just combine together? Then no. The best I can offer now would be more details/pseudo-code on how to implement the above... If I feel like it I could maybe write it under matlab but I think I don't have it anymore (and it'd take me a fair bit of time). I could also offer a complexity analysis/comparison with your previous method.

Comment: Sure, a comparison with my previous method is fine.

Comment: @Arbuja I'll edit it when I get more time... If I don't, ping me again this w-e I guess.

Comment: @Arbuja I'll be honest, I had kinda forgotten to complete my answer, but here you go.